# How can I completely remove NetworkManager?

Tags: network-manager

I want to disable NetworkManager entirely, and have my eth0 and wifi connections unmanaged.  My eth0 on my main linux box is unmanaged and I have no issues with it, I want to do the same to my other linux boxes all running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, basically I want to kill Network Manager and never see any trace of it again.

Comment: "I want to kill Network Manager and never see any trace of it again."  I feel you.

Comment: +1 merely for the frustration expressed here,  and shared whole-heartedly even two years later. I swear NetworkManager was some evil incarnation from Microsoft designed to torpedo Ubuntu.

Comment: Again a +1 for the frustration. We need an alternative!

Comment: Nicely said... Thought I was the only one frustrated at it... +1

Comment: Network manager is an absolutely nightmare, just let us have the configs!

Comment: Don't forget to remove connman too, that will keep overwriting your resolv.conf!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First edit /etc/network/interfaces so that the ifup utility can be used to configure eth0 once NetworkManager is gone.

Remove NetworkManager from the system

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
```

Configure eth0 using ifup.

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

Comment: ifup was what I was looking for, thanks that helps simplify things greatly.

Comment: This also removes gnome-control-center.

Comment: Thanks I can now ping google. What a stupid utility!

Answer (score 16):

Gnome:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

KDE:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge knetworkmanager network-manager
```

Unity : lol, Unity.

Answer (score 5):

It might be worth it to disable it, configure your alternate setup, and then uninstall it.

[Stopping and Disabling NetworkManager | help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Stopping_and_Disabling_NetworkManager)

Answer (score 2):

I did through it may be it will help some one to remove safely Network Manger:

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces` must both be edited for a manual connection otherwise you will be left without full network capability.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 50 rep points to comment, so I'll add some info as an answer that may be helpful.  On a Surface Pro 3 with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, Giving this command:

```
killall -STOP NetworkManager
```

made a dramatic improvement in RTP-over-wireless streaming applications.  NM can be restarted with `-CONT` parameter.  More details here:

[Disable / Enable Periodic Wireless Scans](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2163994)

For the SP3 there are other settings required, including `net.core.xxx` items, and to maintain optimum performance it should remain plugged in.  Likely this info applies to other tablets with Ubuntu also.