# Why do I need to restart Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for my networking scripts to work?

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox, scripts

When I started using 13.04 LTS on my Virtualbox VM (4.3.26), I turned off network manager and wrote some scripts for dynamically updating the static IP of my laptop on any network.  I was doing this so I could take my development environment with me;  I store the settings in a git branch creating a new one with different settings for every network I arrive at for example if I was at tom's house  I would run:

```
$ git checkout tomsHouse
$ sudo ./updateConfiguration.sh
```

or if I was at Starbucks I would run:

```
$ git checkout starbucks
$ sudo ./updateConfiguration.sh
```

The configuration that is loaded is a variant on the following:

```
# Copy the configuration files out to their respective locations...
sudo cp ./dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.conf
sudo cp ./interfaces /etc/network/interfaces

# Restart networking
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start

# Restart the dnsmasq service
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq stop
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq start

# Restart Lampp
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp_stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp_start
```

**./updateConfiguration.sh** - Run this to set the new configuration...the rest are just configuration files...

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.2.45
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1 4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8
```

**./interfaces**

and of course the **dnsmasq.conf** file just updates the rest of the configurations to point to whatever static IP address interfaces points to.

When I upgraded to 14.04 LTS my network switching scripts stopped working, I'm forced to reboot to enabled the changes, whereas before in 13.04 I could just run the script and everything would work again.

Has anything changed in 14.04 that might prevent this from working correctly?

Comment: If you are using sudo to invoke updateConfigurations you don't need to put sudo in every line there. Could it be that network-manager is now controlling your network?. Try to restart it too.

Comment: How to get rid of network manager: http://askubuntu.com/questions/249944/how-can-i-completely-remove-networkmanager