# setting up networking without network-manager

Tags: 12.04, networking, network-manager

A specific application I use doesn't play well with network-manager. I would like to purge network-manager and configure my connections manually.

I have a dhcp connection to the network, and a static ip connection to an ethernet device.

How should I configure my ubuntu?

I tried setting /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
address 192.168.155.130
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 192.168.155.1
```

But that didn't work at all. Are there other things I need to consider?

Comment: Can you qualify *"didn't work at all"*? What do you expect, and what actually happens? What routing are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Remove network manager:

`sudo apt-get purge network-manager`

Alternatively you can disable it without uninstalling:

`sudo stop network-manager
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override`

2. Configure your network interfaces with ifup:

`sudo ifup eth0
sudo ifup eth3`

The interfaces marked with `auto` in /etc/network/interfaces are brought up automatically at boot. So actually this step is only needed to bring them up manually.

To bring an interface down, use `ifdown`.

--

References:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager
- [How can I completely remove NetworkManager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249944/how-can-i-completely-remove-networkmanager)

Comment: There is no need to uninstall or stop NM. It ignores all interfaces listed in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: From what I remember I don't think it does it on 12.04 unless you configure it specifically.

Comment: ifup and ifdown are no longer installed in Ubuntu. I can't add them because I can't bring up the network interface.

Comment: @tim11g: Just install the package `ifupdown` to get them

Comment: @Pilot6: Note that once you add/remove sections from `/etc/network/interfaces`, you need to restart NetworkManager (or reboot) to make it stop managing the port.