# Wake-on-LAN broken on 64 bit, works on 32 bit

Tags: networking, 64-bit, ethernet, 32-bit, wakeonlan

#### How can I get WOL to work on 64 bit Ubuntu?

It's a wierd situation. The hardware is a heavily modified ASUS G75VW 3D. Windows and 32 bit Ubuntu work fine for Wake on LAN. The motherboard has a minor role here, only having some power save settings which I disabled in bios to allow WOL. Then, the NIC has to be configured. On Windows this is a one time setting and it works great. On Ubuntu 32 bit, I used an `rc.local` trigger for `ethtool` and it worked great.

On 32 bit Ubuntu the network card shows up as `eth0` as one might expect. On 64 bit, it get's renamed to `enp4s0`. I know it's renamed because I checked `dmesg`, which also says why my rc.local script doesn't change the `wol` from `d` to `g` in `ethtool`:

```
[    1.624275] atl1c 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
[    3.821446] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp4s0: link is not ready
[    3.822431] atl1c 0000:04:00.0: atl1c: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up<1000 Mbps Full Duplex>
```

ok, whatever. I can deal with the link being not ready, put it on a timer or something for later. But if I set it manually, ethtool says it's showing wol g for the card

```
Supports Wake-on: pg
Wake-on: g
```

For some reason, this gets reset when I shutdown the computer, because the wol magic packet does not wake the computer even after this.

### Testing

I've tested a lot of things. First, the wol trigger does not work if the laptop has been unplugged, even briefly. It does work if the ethernet cable has been unplugged and plugged back in. The wol trigger is clearly being set as the OS shuts down because if I shutdown 32 bit ubuntu and swap the hard drives without unplugging, I can WOL into 64 bit ubuntu.

I suspect it has something to do with the drivers, but I don't know where to get them if that's the case. Then again, can I just run the 32 bit driver on 64 bit and be done with it? I have 32 bit libs on the machine for other purposes.

I can't solve this by running 32 bit ubuntu, because I run JVMs on the machine that require a large amount of RAM (beyond the 32 bit limit).

Per the [ubuntu help docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan) I removed `network-manager` and attempted to configure the connection with `ifup` ([from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/249972/123532)). Unfortunately, ifup didn't recognize the interface. Here were the contents of my `/etc/network/interfaces` file in 64 bit.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I don't know why my wireless and ethernet card were not listed there. Here is `ifconfig -a`.

```
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:bf:48:19:08:b4
          inet addr:192.168.1.91  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::12bf:48ff:fe19:8b4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:48646 (48.6 KB)  TX bytes:38816 (38.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:8091 (8.0 KB)  TX bytes:8091 (8.0 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:85:08:70:7d:7b
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

So per [a forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1021210) I added `enp4s0` manually to the network interfaces file. It now looks like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
```

Then ifup worked. I don't know if I did it right, but all I did was type:

```
ifup enp4s0
```

Everything still worked and I could still SSH in after a restart, so I guess I haven't yet broken my ethernet card. I really don't know what I'm doing here guys and I'm grasping at straws.

I read a little further down the help page and realized I overlooked [the link to a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/981461).

Following the workaround, I added a script to `rc6.d` and `rc0.d` and set them to executable but I'm not sure how to check if the actually executed (I guess I could `echo` something and check `dmesg`...would that work?). I rebooted the machine once for good measure and powered it down, but it still did not come up with WOL attempts.

Following the rabbit hole I found [a comment on a blog post](http://confoundedtech.blogspot.com/2011/06/enable-wol-on-ubuntu-hp-microserver.html?showComment=1321625607248#c6681025261024168629) which suggested a more specific static IP address would help. I didn't see why (since magic packet sends to the entire network with a mac address), but I tried it anyway. If my configuration for network interfaces looks like his, there is no change.

Further details about the machine. Both 32 bit and 64 bit are on the latest `Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf`.

---

### Update

I have more research.

I can confirm that WoL works on a fresh install of Wily Werewolf 64 bit.  Following that, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then WoL stopped working.  That appears to be the only steps necessary to reproduce my issue.

---

So again, here's my question:

#### How can I get wake on lan to work in 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: Do rclocal scripts even work with systemd or are you using upstart or something?

Comment: If you would like to rename the device to eth0 see here http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.hellovinoth.com/ubuntu-14-04-renaming-ethernet-interfaces-from-p1p1%25E2%2580%25B3-to-eth0%25E2%2580%25B3/

Comment: thanks @mchid, working on the rename now.  `rc.local` has always worked fine.  I use it on my raspberry pis and lots of VMs & cloud instances.  I know there's a better way (changing the interfaces to trigger it as it "up"s but that doesn't work either so it doesn't matter.  `rc.local` works fine on 32 bit was all I was saying

Comment: attempted to follow the tutorial to fix the name. there are no files in `/etc/udev/rules.d` on the machine.  I tried to follow the bit about adding the interface, but write_net_rules does not exist in the `/lib/udev` folder

Comment: I'll have to test it out there is also some really good info available from are arch linux when I get in front of a box I'll post an update.

Comment: updated after more testing

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally found an answer to this problem. In the version 15.10 the TLP utilities has been introduced as default. So on dist upgrade you get a default configuration in TLP saying WOL_DISABLE=Y

Even https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN says if the computer does not wake after suspend/hibernate when using TLP, set the WOL_DISABLE value to N in /etc/default/tlp.

I have tested this on Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 LTS (64bit) where WOL didn't work after installation. Changing the configuration of TLP makes it work again.

I hope this helps in your problem too.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, but I expect it will work fine and then you'll get the correct answer tick

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with the options of the ethernet card, I found a setting in the advanced tab that's called "Shutdown wake up" that was disabled for me. I enabled it and now it works! Hope that helps someone else with the same problem.